# How do I solve given typedef in C

Tags: c, typedef

I have a couple of typedef statement but now sure whats the original type it has

```
 typedef unsigned int addrt;
 typedef addrt addr32t;
```

Is  "addr32t" nothing but an unsigned integer??

Comment: yes, is an alias of unsigned int

Comment: What did you expect? That it was a char*** ?

Comment: But take care, addr32t has no guarantee to be 32 bits as the name suggests, take a look to uint32_t http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/stdint.h.html

Answer (score 5):

- `addrt` is an alias of `unsigned int`.
- `addr32t` is an alias of `addrt`, therefore an alias of `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 5):

> Is "addr32t" nothing but an unsigned integer??

Yes.

Comment: How, you found a way to answer quickly without being blocked by the 30 char? xD

Comment: well one line questions deserve one line answers , what more can i say :) ??

Comment: @Geoffroy Happens to me too.. sometime the best answer is simply: "Yes". xD